# changing a single bit in an arduino EEPROM byte

Tags: eeprom, bit

In my code I have a number of boolean flags that tell me if data has been written to specific places in the EEPROM. I need to save these flags to the EEPROM and recover them on a restart.

Is the following syntax valid to update a single bit in an EEPROM cell?

```
EEPROM.update (0, EEPROM.read(0)| 0x20);
```

ie I'm reading cell '0' , putting a '1' into bit 5 and then updating cell; '0' of the EEPROM. There will be several other bits to be updated throughout the running of the programme.

Comment: how frequently?

Comment: perehaps you better first collect all bit changes and update the value only once.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your syntax is indeed correct. The `|` operator is the bitwise OR operator in C and C++, and it's used to set a specific bit in a byte. Here's a breakdown of what your line of code does:

- `EEPROM.read(0)` reads the current value of the first byte in the EEPROM.
- `0x20` is the hexadecimal representation of 32, which is `00100000` in binary. This means that the fifth bit (counting from zero) is set to 1, and all other bits are set to 0.
- `EEPROM.read(0) | 0x20` performs a bitwise OR operation on the current value of the first byte in the EEPROM and `0x20`. This will set the fifth bit of the byte to 1, and leave the other bits unchanged.
- `EEPROM.update(0, EEPROM.read(0) | 0x20)` updates the first byte in the EEPROM with the new value.

So, your approach to set a specific bit in an EEPROM byte is correct.

Here's a more detailed example:

```cpp
byte bitToSet = 5; // Bit number to set (0-7)
byte eepromAddress = 0; // EEPROM address (0-1023 for ATmega328)

// Read current value
byte currentValue = EEPROM.read(eepromAddress);

// Create mask for bit to set
byte mask = 1 << bitToSet;

// Update value
byte newValue = currentValue | mask;

// Write updated value back to EEPROM
EEPROM.update(eepromAddress, newValue);
```

It's worth noting that the `EEPROM.update()` function is smart enough to only perform a write if the new value is different from the old one. This is important because the EEPROM has a limited number of write cycles. So using `EEPROM.update()` instead of `EEPROM.write()` can help extend the life of the EEPROM.

Comment: Note: unprogrammed eeprom/flash values are 0xFF so if you left it unprogrammed it might not work as intended